# Flutter pub get failed on upgraded version of flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

after installing new version of `flutter` i can't run `flutter pub get` command and i get this error:

```
Because photofeeler requires SDK version >=3.0.0-0 <4.0.0, version solving failed.

pub get failed
command: "D:\develop\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart __deprecated_pub --color --directory . get --example"
pub env: {
  "FLUTTER_ROOT": "D:\develop\flutter",
  "PUB_ENVIRONMENT": "flutter_cli:get",
  "PUB_CACHE": "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache",
}
exit code: 1
```

upgrading flutter is ok and when i run `flutter upgrade` command i get this result:

```
flutter upgrade
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
Flutter 3.7.7 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 2ad6cd72c0 (2 weeks ago) • 2023-03-08 09:41:59 -0800
Engine • revision 1837b5be5f
Tools • Dart 2.19.4 • DevTools 2.20.1
PS D:\develop\flutter-projects\photofeeler> flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in photofeeler...
Resolving dependencies... 
The current Dart SDK version is 2.19.4.
```

`flutter doctor` output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1413], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.74.3)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

and my `pubspec.yaml` contains:

```yaml
name: mysample
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.0-0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  equatable: ^2.0.5
  dio: ^5.0.3
  #...


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.1
  build_runner: ^2.3.3
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.12.0
  freezed: ^2.1.0+1
  freezed_annotation: ^2.2.0
  functional_widget: any
  json_serializable: ^6.6.1
  lint: ^2.1.1
  hive_generator: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
    - assets/images/
    - assets/fonts/
  fonts:
    - family: Sans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Sans.ttf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with this line in your `pubspec.yaml` restricting your project to a Dart 3.0 SDK:

```yaml
environment:
  # This is the Dart SDK version constraints
  sdk: '>=3.0.0-0 <4.0.0'
```

Flutter `3.7.7` is shipped with Dart `2.19.4`, so you'll need to loosen the constraints to `sdk: '>=2.19.0 <3.0.0'` (or `sdk: '>=2.19.0 <4.0.0'` if your project is Dart 3.0 ready or you want to move to a beta branch with a beta version of Dart 3.0).